# How to inject code into an arm64e process in macOS?

Tags: macos, code-injection, arm64, apple-silicon

I've written [a utility](https://github.com/briankendall/forceFullDesktopBar) that modifies system behavior by injecting compiled code (in the form of a dylib) into the Dock using the old [`mach_inject`](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject) method. However, `mach_inject` hasn't been updated in several years now and doesn't work on Apple Silicon macs.

Is there another method I can use to inject and execute code from a dylib into arm64e processes? `mach_inject` creates a thread in the target process and executes the payload in that thread, so I'd need it to do something similar.

I've been pointed to [frida](https://frida.re) as a possible alternative but it seems to be catered towards interacting with a target process through a javascript runtime, rather than injecting already compiled code into a process. I haven't been able to figure out if it can do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives

## [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai)

- Before commit [inline mach_bootstrap as shell code](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/commit/8ff93d5a7cf8d4d7709bd1e3ee433f2706d70c06)

`yabai` used [mechanic of `mach_inject`](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/commit/8e558fff8bf8282074082cdefab1894ef57b7171) and added [arm64 support](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/commit/766d9ea3831dc5e6c0e0d4626220834bf903399d)

- After `yabai` uses assembly from [Code injection on macOS](https://knight.sc/malware/2019/03/15/code-injection-on-macos.html), same as `MacForge`
- `yabai` [support arm64e](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/commit/c7a3b759b61dc5aa6d0722fe40dea12941b3867b) and [check `-arm64e_preview_abi`](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/commit/6bfbbc4febb9f8fe935ed11053f5ef2a36d23436) with [help from Jeremy Legendre](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/commit/a8eb6b1a7da4e33954b716b424eb51ce47317865)

## [MacForge](https://github.com/MacEnhance/MacForge)

- MacPlus used `mach_inject` first
- [Jeremy Legendre](https://github.com/jslegendre) provided [UniversalInj.h/c](https://github.com/MacEnhance/MacForge/commit/44f1c98521850e7978de76a0bbab2f8eca4c89d7)

There are several updates of `UniversalInj.h/c` afterwards. I'm not sure about `-arm64e_preview_abi` support

Answer (score 0):

Frida has a component called Frida-core which includes a C API for injecting code into processes. An example demonstrating its use can be found here: [frida-core-example-unix.c](https://github.com/frida/frida/blob/master/releng/devkit-assets/frida-core-example-unix.c).

It can be used to inject dylibs using javascript like the following:

```
var RTLD_NOW = 0x02;
var _dlopen = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName(null, "dlopen"), 'pointer', ['pointer', 'int']);
var path = Memory.allocUtf8String("/path/to/dylib");
_dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW);
```

Unfortunately it is a very heavy weight library and causes the resultant binaries to be around 50 MB in size, 100 MB for a universal binary, but so far it's the only one I've found that works!